# Confusing returns and scanf issue related

Tags: c, if-statement, printf

I was having some problem with a scanf statement being skipped, but I read that it tends to eat the previous \n etc..
Now that I have my char actually going through my if statement it is only returning my else, even though I can guarantee that the if statement is obtaining a proper value.

Do y'all see where my code might be blundered?

I have not included my headers or anything because it is a fairly large block of code, but it runs perfectly up to this point.

```
  char oakAns;

  printf("Would you like the sign made out of oak?\n");
  printf("Enter y for yes or n for no: ");
  
  scanf(" %c",&oakAns);
  
  printf("%c",oakAns);  //this is what i was using to confirm my oakAns input

  
  if((oakAns == 'y')||(oakAns == 'Y')){          // if y then add 15
    cost += 15;
  } 
  if((oakAns == 'n')||(oakAns == 'N')){    // but if n then remain same
    cost = 30;
  }
  else {                      // anything else returns false
    printf("Could not compute cost...\n");
  
    return false;
  }
```

Comment: Your `else` applies **only** to the second `if`. As your answer is (supposed to be) `'Y'`, it is not `'N'` and that makes the `else` execute. Your program is adding `15` to the `cost` because it is an `'Y'` **and** printing the `"Could not compute"` message because it is not a `'N'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the problem in the if statements. Instead of these statements

```
  if((oakAns == 'y')||(oakAns == 'Y')){          // if y then add 15
    cost += 15;
  } 
  if((oakAns == 'n')||(oakAns == 'N')){    // but if n then remain same
    cost = 30;
  }
  else {                      // anything else returns false
    printf("Could not compute cost...\n");
```

you shoudl write

```
  if((oakAns == 'y')||(oakAns == 'Y')){          // if y then add 15
    cost += 15;
  } 
  else if((oakAns == 'n')||(oakAns == 'N')){    // but if n then remain same
    cost = 30;
  }
  else {                      // anything else returns false
    printf("Could not compute cost...\n");
```

That is this if statement

```
  if((oakAns == 'n')||(oakAns == 'N')){    // but if n then remain same
```

should be an else part of the previous if statement.

Otherwise the message outputted by this call of printf

```
    printf("Could not compute cost...\n");
```

will be always outputted if the user will enter either `'y'` or `'Y'`.